# Stack Exchange experimentation sandbox

Tags: support

This is a sandbox post for users to experiment with various Stack Exchange features. This question (and all answers) is a community wiki so that the reputation required to edit is lower.

Also, the user who owns this post is set to [Community](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community), which is not a real user but a background process. So you needn't worry that some one might be notified by all your shenanigans here (do note that comments on others' answers will still notify them).

Feel free to post an answer (gibberish welcome), delete your answers as you wish, try out various formatting tricks, test out voting to close/delete, protect posts, test new privileges, whatever the hell you want ([yes, really!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)). Of course, as always, offensive content/spam will not be tolerated.

I merely request that you do not change the title of this post or add any new arbitrary tags. If you do cast the last close/delete vote or if it is not reopened, please let a ♦ moderator know so that we can reopen/undelete it.

Feel free to modify the question below this line

---

Comment: @foo @bar` test comment

Answer (score 2):

SoundCloud test:

http://soundcloud.com/datageist/example-7-analog-kick-drum